# Magnitude of Normal Force in Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

[image]

In the above diagram an object is in vertical circular motion.

At $T_0$ the object is at pos1, and at that position, I have shown the forces resolved. So $F_n-mg\cos(a)$ is the centripetal force towards the centre.

Now at next instant $T_1$, what is the guarantee that $F_n - mg\cos(a)$ is just enough to change the trajectory of the object to pos2 but not pos3?

Comment: What is normal force at pos2? What is it at pos3?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a bit difficult to develop some intuition about normal forces. Try to think of it from the other side. You have circular motion. Whatever the forces are, you know that your object is moving on a circle. Then there must be a force responsible for keeping the object on the circle.

Physically, this force comes from the black loop. This represents a solid object (the rails of a roller-coaster, for example) that pushes back when something tries to bend it. Instead of going into the dynamics of elastic bodies, we just say that the black circle is very stiff. It reacts instantly in such a way that your object moves along the circle. The normal force will always be
$$Fn = m\frac{v(t)^2}{r} + mg \cos(\alpha(t)) \, ,$$
for all values of $t$ because it is a given that your object moves along a circle. If this were not the case, then the object would either fall towards the centre of the circle or break the material of the black circle and leave the circular motion.

Note that you can actually use this interpretation to compute the minimum speed required for the circular motion to be possible. Indeed, the normal force can only point towards the centre of the circular motion. A negative value of $Fn$ would imply that we have a sticky track for the roller-coaster. At the top of the loop we have
$$Fn = mv^2/r - mg \, .$$
$Fn$ can only be positive if $v^2>r g$.

Answer (score 0):

I've done an interesting analysis which may help with your understanding.  It takes into account the slowing down of the object as it rises up the track and the speeding up of the object as it moves downward along the track.  I assumed that the object maintains contact with the track at all locations around the loop, except at the very top where the normal force just barely becomes zero.  Under these circumstances, the centripetal acceleration and the normal force are described by the following equations:
$$\frac{v^2}{r}=3g+2g\cos{a}$$
$$F_n=3mg(1+\cos{a})$$
According to these relationships, at the very bottom of the loop ($a=0$), $\frac{v^2}{r}=5g$ and $F_n=6mg$, while at the top of the loop ($a=\pi$), $\frac{v^2}{r}=g$ and $F_n=0$. So, at the bottom of the loop, the normal force is 6g's, while, at the top of the loop, the object is in free fall.  If the velocity at the very bottom is less than $\sqrt{5gr}$, the object will lose contact with the track before reaching the top of the loop.

Answer (score -1):

What guarantees that, is the fact that centripetal force must be exactly balanced by centrifugal force. And the magnitude of centrifugal force is a function of tangential velocity. So some angular velocity produces circular motion, while some other angular velocity produces other kind of motion, like spiral.